# Inserting a blank row after a string in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro in excel 2010 that finds every cell in a sheet with a value of "All Customers."  Every time that value is found I need a blank row inserted below it. Thought it would be pretty simple but I have searched I many forums and tried to use some sample code and I can't get it to work properly. I am a complete newb when it comes to VBA stuff. Thought I would post here and go do some light reading on basics of VBA.

If anyone has any good training resources, please post those as well.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: In my OP, I neglected to mention that any row that contains a value of "All Customers" would ideally be highlighted and put in bold, increased size font.

These actions are something that an old Crystal Report viewing/formatting program used to handle automatically when pulling the report. After we upgraded the program I learned that this type of formatting ability had been removed with the release of the newer version of the program, according to the software manufacturer's tech support. Had this been defined in the release notes I would have not performed the upgrade. Regardless, that is how I found myself in this macro disaster.

Comment: You should post the coce you tried, and describe the errors you get, or describe in what way it "doesn't work"

Comment: Tim, thanks for the note. The code I had attempted to use from another source was not intended for the purpose I tried to use it for. So, essentially I had nothing. In an attempt to not over-complicate anything, starting from scratch and explaining the task at hand seemed to be the best option versus posting some random code that in no way applied to how I wanted to use it.

Comment: Is "All Customers" the only content of the cells you'rel ooking for, or is it part of a larger piece of text? Does it occur in a particular column? If found should the whole row be bolded, or just the one cell?

Comment: All Customers is the only content in the cell. It only occurs in column A. If found, it would be ideal to have the entire row highlight and placed in bold font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this code adpated from [an article of mine here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2919-Using-Find-and-FindNext-to-efficiently-delete-any-rows-that-contain-specific-text.html) is efficient and avoids looping

1. It bolds and increase the font size where the text is found (in the entire row, as Tim points out you should specify whether you meant by cell only)
2. It adds a blank row below the matches

**code**

```
Option Explicit

Const strText As String = "All Customers"

Sub ColSearch_DelRows()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Dim cel2 As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String
    Dim lAppCalc As Long
    Dim bParseString As Boolean

    'Get working range from user
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select range to search for " & strText, "User range selection", ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address(0, 0), , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Further processing of matches
    bParseString = True

    With Application
        lAppCalc = .Calculation
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'a) match string to entire cell, case insensitive
    'Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, , False)

    'b) match string to entire cell, case sensitive
    'Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, , True)

    'c)match string to part of cell, case insensititive
     Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, , False)

    'd)match string to part of cell, case sensititive
    ' Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, , True)

    'A range variable - rng2 - is used to store the range of cells that contain the string being searched for
    If Not cel1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng2 = cel1
        strFirstAddress = cel1.Address
        Do
            Set cel1 = rng1.FindNext(cel1)
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2.EntireRow, cel1)
        Loop While strFirstAddress <> cel1.Address
    End If

    'Further processing of found range if required
    If bParseString Then
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        With rng2
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 20
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End With
    End If
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lAppCalc
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! I just need to figure out how to add highlighting to the entire row. That should be a good task for me now that I at least have a working solution that covers 98% of what is needed.

Comment: to highlight the entire row change `.Font.Bold = True` to `.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True` , the same for font size if required

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub InsertRowAfterCellFound()

    Dim foundRange As Range
    Set foundRange = Cells.Find(What:="yourStringOrVariant", After:=ActiveCell) 'Find the range with the occurance of the required variant

    Rows(foundRange.Row + 1 & ":" & foundRange.Row + 1).Insert 'Insert a new row below the row of the foundRange row

    foundRange.Activate 'Set the found range to be the ActiveCell, this is a quick and easy way of ensuring you aren't repeating find from the top

End Sub
```

You may need to add error handling to the code as you will get an error if no cell with the specified value is found.

Comment: When I attempted to run your chunk of code it did insert a blank row after the first "All Customers" value was found. There are a total of 6 cells with "All Customers" in this particular example spreadsheet I am testing with. Can you point in the right direction of how to adjust this code to recognize every instance of "All Customers" in the sheet?

Comment: If you only ran it once then it would only have found the first instance. If you were to run it more than once it would automatically search for the next occurrence of "All Customers" as it is set as the ActiveCell. You could always put the code in a for loop and loop 6 times.

Comment: This solution worked for me the best. However, I had to hold the F5 key to loop through my 20000+ rows. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is on the first sheet ("sheet 1"), here is a slow answer:

```
Sub InsertRowsBelowAllCustomers()

    'Set your worksheet to a variable
    Dim sheetOne as Worksheet 
    Set sheetOne = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Find the total number of used rows and columns in the sheet (where "All Customers" could be)
    Dim totalRows, totalCols as Integer
    totalRows = sheetOne.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    totalCols = sheetOne.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'Loop through all used rows/columns and find your desired "All Customers"
    Dim row, col as Integer
    For row = 1 to totalRows
        For col = 1 to totalCols
            If sheetOne.Cells(row,col).Value = "All Customers" Then
                  Range(sheetOne.Cells(row,col)).Select
                  ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                  totalRows = totalRows + 1 'increment totalRows because you added a new row
                  Exit For  
            End If 
        Next col
    Next row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This function starts from the last row and goes back up to the first row, inserting an empty row after each cell containing "All Customers" on column A:

```
Sub InsertRowsBelowAllCustomers()
  Dim R As Integer
  For R = UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(R, 1) = "All Customers" Then Rows(R + 1).Insert
  Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: I attempted to use the code you provided and it returns run-time error 424: Object Required. When I run debug it highlights line 3. Should I be using something other than usedrange.rows.count?

Comment: I tried and it works for me, both running it from the VBA editor and by clicking a button on the sheet. How do you run it?  What is the missing object?  You can find it out by clicking the Debug button when you get the error message, then selecting a variable in the current line, then pressing Shift+F9. If you select `UsedRange` and press Shif+F9 it should show the Value field empty. If it shows an error message then that's where the problem is.  
If that's good (no value) then try by selecting `UsedRange.Rows` and pressing Shift+F9, etc.

Comment: When I click the debug option and do shift+f9 it displays a message stating "no watch expression selected." To run, I go to View tab, Macros, view macros, and run from there. I get the same thing when I run out of VBA. I have used brettdj's code and so far it is working. Thanks for your time on this, I don't want you to waste any more time on it now that I have a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the worksheet was not specified in used range. 
I have slightly altered the code with my text being in column AJ and inserting a row above the cell.

```
Dim R As Integer

For R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

  If Range("AJ" & R) = "Combo" Then Rows(R).Insert

Next R
```